# Having Trouble Compiling (C++)

Tags: c++

I've began learning C++, and I'm having an issue compiling. I am doing so on the Microsoft Visual Studio Command Prompt. When I type `cl /EHsc hello.cpp` I get this error:

```
fatal error C10083: Cannot open source file 'hello.cpp': No such file or directory
```

I created the file via the command prompt by using

```
notepad hello.cpp
```

And I created the file, typed the correct code in (you know... the hello world stuff, haha), saved it.

If anyone could help me, that would be great, thanks!

Comment: I assume it may be saved as hello.cpp.txt, please check it

Answer (score -1):

Use this tool to quickly find your .cpp file, http://www.voidtools.com

After you find it make sure to copy it to the required folder and use the "save as" feature on notepad to save your next files where they should be saved with the correct extension.

Comment: Thanks - what is the correct folder by default, if you know?

Comment: That depends up to you, you can choose where to store your files and include the full path into the compiler command line, or leave the files inside the compiler folder or on the environment paths, the best way would be to create a folder on your PC where you keep your source files for the project and a separate folder for the output, just so you get used from the beginning to keep your code clean and organized.